# Hide div if agents offline with Live Chat Inc

Tags: javascript, html, css, livechat

I am using LiveChat on my website and trying to show a div if no agents are available, using their guide [here](https://developers.livechat.com/docs/extending-chat-widget/javascript-api/v1.0/#agents-are-available)

**Javascript**

```
LC_API.on_after_load = function() {
    if (LC_API.agents_are_available()) {
        $("#ChatLink2").hide(); 
    } else {
        $("#ChatLink2").show();    
    }   
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='ChatLink2' id='ChatLink2'>Currently Unavailable</div>
```

However, the div `ChatLink2` is not showing when no agents are available

Comment: I'd debug this first, to check it's not something going on with LiveChat. Can you add `console.log("Unavailable");` above `$("#ChatLink2").show();` and see if it's meeting the expected condition?

Comment: In the browser console (Developer Tools), you should see "Unavailable" printed if there are no agents. You could similarly add an "Available" one to prove it meets that condition too. Note these should be removed before you put your site live, they should only be used for debug,

Comment: Yes, I see this printed...

Comment: Accessing Developer Tools - then select Console: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open

Comment: I am actually only seeing it for 'Available' and nothing for 'Unavailable'

Comment: Okay the console is now showing both 'Available' and 'Unavailable' correctly.  But the div is showing all the time...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227591/discussion-between-jay-hewitt-and-designer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be race conditions with both LiveChat and JQuery. Below checks for LC availability and uses vanilla JS instead of jQuery.

Also included state change callback if agents go offline after init.

```
var waitForLC = setInterval(function () {
    if (window.LC_API === undefined) {
        return;
    }
    clearInterval(waitForLC);
    var showUnavailableStatus = function(show){
        var statusDiv = document.getElementById("ChatLink2");
        var style = show ? "block" : "none";
        statusDiv.style.display = style;
    }
    LC_API.on_after_load = function() {
        if (LC_API.agents_are_available()) {
            showUnavailableStatus(false);
        } else {
            showUnavailableStatus(true);
        }
    };
    LC_API.on_chat_state_changed = function(data) {
        showUnavailableStatus(data.state==="offline");
    };
}, 100);
```